# How to run Custom query on audit table hibernate envers

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

Trying to retreive records through custom query on **audit** table. I have **Hibernate** entity structure like below..,

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class TableA {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PrimaryKeyID primaryKeyID;
    private Double price;
    private Date modifiedOn;
    private String status;
}
@Embeddable
public class PrimaryKeyID implements Serializable {
    private Integer Id;
}
```

The query I am trying to replicate through AuditFactory is

```
SELECT * FROM table_A_aud where id = ? and status=? order by modifiedOn desc limit 3;
```

Tried **Hibernate** document on the **Envers** but I didnt find much info on that. Can someone kindly help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to issue a query against the audit tables, you would do the following:

```
List results = AuditReaderFactory.get( session )
  .createQuery()
  .forRevisionsOfEntity( TableA.class, true, false )
  .add( AuditEntity.id().eq( entityId ) )
  .add( AuditEntity.property( "status" ).eq( entityStatus ) )
  .addOrder( AuditEntity.property( "modifiedOn" ).desc() )
  .setMaxResults( 3 )
  .getResultList();
```

In this query, we instruct the reader to get only entity instances (excluding delete markers) where the entity id is equal to `entityId` and the status is equal to `entityStatus` and ordering the results based on the `modifiedOn` column in descending order.

You'll notice that a lot of this Query API mimics that of the legacy Hibernate Criteria API.